# Chart.js annotation plugin - Box not being displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-annotation

I'm using **chart.js@2.9.4** and **chartjs-plugin-annotation@0.5.7** in a Vue 2 project. I was able to build a chart with a line but the box is always expanded out to the edges, I'm not sure if the issue is related with my x-axis, since the values are strings (months).

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import AnnotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

Chart.plugins.register(AnnotationPlugin);

new Chart(lineChart.value, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
      ],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Dataset 1',
          data: [120, 125, 128, 121, 130, 125, 135],
          borderColor: '#018572',
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          lineTension: 0.1,
          fill: false,
        },
        {
          label: 'Dataset 2',
          data: [81, 85, 88, 90, 83, 82, 80],
          borderColor: '#9F642C',
          backgroundColor: 'brown',
          lineTension: 0.1,
          fill: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Line Chart',
      },
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'top',
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 80,
          fontColor: 'black',
        },
      },
      annotation: {
        annotations: [
          {
            drawTime: 'afterDraw',
            id: 'a-line-1',
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'horizontal',
            scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
            value: '25',
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 2,
          },
          {
            type: 'box',
            drawTime: 'beforeDatasetsDraw',
            id: 'a-box-1',
            xScaleID: 'x',
            xMax: 'July',
            xMin: 'January',
            yScaleID: 'y',
            yMax: 140,
            yMin: 120,
            backgroundColor: 'green',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
```

This is the result that I'm always getting:

[image]

I need to decrease the box in the y-axis since I need to show two bands in the chart.
I'll really appreciate any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is related to `xScaleID` and `yScaleID` values. You set `'x'` and `'y'` as values but in chart.js 2, the default scales IDs are different. In fact, in the line annotation, you are setting `'y-axis-0'`.
That said, I think setting `xScaleID: 'x-axis-0'` and `yScaleID: 'y-axis-0'` should work.